# C++ assign a variable pointer address

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to receive a variable of type DWORD which will contain address pointer float *.
If I write this:

```
float *Object = 5;  
std::cout << &Object;
```

It gives me exactly the value that I want (i.e: `0F235C1A`).
Can you tell me how to assign this value to DWORD for using it in my Memory Write function?
Trying:

```
DWORD ObjAddress = &Object;
```

I got compiler error:  `cannot convert from 'float *' to 'DWORD'`

Comment: I doubt your first code does what you expect it to. Also what's the definition of `DWORD`?

Comment: What about typecasting? (DWORD) &Object

Comment: @Jefffrey [`DWORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx) is a microsoft typedef'd `unsigned long`

Comment: You may want to show your MemoryWrite function too.

Comment: `float *Object = 5;` shouldn't compile, for one thing. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Note that `DWORD` is a Win32/64 type, and on Win64 it cannot hold a `float*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your object definition:

```
float *Object = 5;
```

The 5 should be an address? a value?

See following code, maybe it is what you want.

```
float Object = 5;
int ObjAddress =  (int)&Object;
cout << "object adr1: "<< hex << &Object << endl;
cout << "object adr2: "<< hex << ObjAddress << endl;
```

Output

```
object adr1: 0x28ff08
object adr2: 28ff08
```

Or when you really need the object as a pointer

```
float value = 5;
float *Object = &value;
int ObjAddress =  (int)&Object;
cout << "object adr1: "<< hex << &Object << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast your &Object;

```
DWORD ObjAddress = (DWORD)&Object;
```

And I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: ... and create another. Wielding C-casts blindly to shut the compiler up is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use reinterpret_cast like this (replace unsigned long with DWORD)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    float *object  = new float;

    *object = 5;

    unsigned long objAddress = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(&object);

    std::cout<<objAddress<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```